# Perl: find whether an particular element of array is a word or sentence

Tags: perl

I have an array which contains text file ...so how to find the array elements which contain just one word by using perl?

Comment: Show us your code and then we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say file content is stored in `@lines`

```
my @words = grep /^\S+$/, @lines;
```

---

**Note :** Don't forget `chomp @lines;` before any further processing.